# [C++]Why Iterating over a std::string using std::stringstream gives an exception character?

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

I'm trying to implement a simple format function that fills in the corresponding content based on the given format character.
I use `std::stringstream` to convert the given format string into a stream, and then take out the characters one by one. Then, based on the individual characters, fill in the relevant content into the output stream.
The format string is given in `std::string` type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string fmt = "[%t]%Y-%M-%D<%H:%m:%s>:%c";
    std::stringstream s_res;
    std::stringstream s_fmt(fmt);
    while (s_fmt.good()) {
        char c = (char) s_fmt.get();
        if (c == '\0') break; // I'm not sure this stagement is necessary.
        if (c == '%') {
            switch (s_fmt.peek()) {
                case 't':
                    s_res << "Type";
                    break;
                case 'Y':
                    s_res << "Year";
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    s_res << "Month";
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    s_res << "Day";
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    s_res << "Hour";
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    s_res << "min";
                    break;
                case 's':
                    s_res << "sec";
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    s_res << "content";
                    break;
            }
            s_fmt.get();
            continue;
        }
        s_res << c;
    }
    std::cout << s_res.str();
    return 0;
}
```

As expected, the program should output something like this:

```
Expected output: [Type]Year-Month-Day<Hour:min:sec>:content
```

But at the end of the expected output, there is a strange character:

```
Actual Output:[Type]Year-Month-Day<Hour:min:sec>:content
========================================================^
```

I checked for a long time and was very troubled to find no credible explanation or concrete solution.

Is this a problem caused by encoding?

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The output statement should be `std::cout << s_res.str() << std::endl;`  (or `'\n'` instead of endl), it's not well-defined what happens if the last line does not end in a newline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that the last character in the stream has just been processed. There's nothing left in the stream.

```
while (s_fmt.good()) {
```

This is perfectly fine. After all, why wouldn't it be? Everything worked swimmingly well, up until now. The entire string has been read. Everything is still `good()`. The `while` loop continues to run:

```
   char c = (char) s_fmt.get();
```

Unfortunately, the end of the string has already been reached. This fails, and  [when the end of the stream has been reached](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) `get()` returns

> `EOF` and sets failbit and eofbit.

The shown code does not check that, and blindly converts the returned `EOF` value to a `char`. That's your "strange character". And on the next iteration of the `while` loop, it will discover that things aren't `good()` any more (the previous `get()` failed), and bail out. Too late.

To fix this it will be necessary to logically rearrange the sequence of events. First you `get()` the next character, and only then you can check if the stream is `good()`, and bail out otherwise. Or, alternatively, check for an explicit `EOF` return value, your preference.